# Sorting one list based on order defined in another list in Java 8

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I have this scenario where I have to sort `listA` based on the order of elements in `listB`.

But the problem I am facing is that if there is that if `listA` contains an element which is not defined in the `listB` then the sort result has all contents of `listA` sorted as per order in `listB` but the element which is not defined in `listB` as the first element.

*Example*

*Input:*

```
listA = [us,au,in,gb]
listB = [au,us,in]    // sort order list
```

*Current Output:*

```
listA = [gb,au,us,in]  // result after sorting
```

*Expected Output:*

```
listA = [au,us,in,gb]  // result after sorting
```

Here, since `"gb"` is not present in the sort list `listB`, the result has `"gb"` as the **first** element, but I want that to be the **last** element.

I am using the below code to sort the `listA`:

```
listA.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(listB::indexOf));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be performance wise to generate a `HashMap` associating the string elements with the corresponding indices (i.e. `Map<String,Integer>`), instead of relaying on `List.indexOf()` method which performs iteration under the hood. And then define a `Comparator` based on this Map.

In order to place the elements that not are not present in the `listB` at the end of the sorted list, we can make use of the method `Map.getOrDefault()` providing the size of the map as a default value.

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<>(List.of("us","au","in","gb"));
List<String> listB = new ArrayList<>(List.of("au","us","in"));
        
Map<String, Integer> order = IntStream.range(0, listB.size())
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        listB::get,
        Function.identity()
    ));
        
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> order.getOrDefault(s, order.size()));
        
listA.sort(comparator);
    
System.out.println(listA);
```

*Output:*

```
[au, us, in, gb]
```

In case in you want to preserve the initial order of the elements in `listA` that are not present in the `listB` (i.e. group them at the very end of the list according to their initial ordering), you can generate an additional `Map`. This time based on the `listA`, which associate each element like `gb` with a unique Value greater or equal to the size of `listB`:

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<>(List.of("fr","us","nl","au","in","gb"));
List<String> listB = new ArrayList<>(List.of("au","us","in"));
        
Map<String, Integer> order = IntStream.range(0, listB.size())
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        listB::get,
        Function.identity()
    ));
    
Map<String, Integer> resolver = IntStream.range(0, listA.size())
    .filter(i -> !order.containsKey(listA.get(i))) // to reduce the size of the Map
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        listA::get,
        i -> i + order.size()
    ));
        
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(
    s -> order.getOrDefault(s, resolver.get(s))
);
        
listA.sort(comparator);
```

*Output:*

```
[au, us, in, fr, nl, gb]   // the order of "fr","nl","gb" is preserved
```

Answer (score 0):

just a quick hack but,

```
public class ExList extends ArrayList<String> {
    public int indexOf(String s) {
       int returnValue = super.indexOf(s);
       if ( returnValue == -1 ) {
           return size();
       }
       return returnValue;
    }
}
```

and create listB as instance of ExList, it would give you a desired result.